# PHP Mail Client

Tags: php, email, client

I have a need to read the 'body' of the most recent email received using PHP (not interested in sender, etc...), but I am not at all sure how to do this. The mail server uses IMAP

http://ryerson.ca/ccs/email/rmail/clients/ConfiguringMozillaThunderbird.pdf <--Uses the same server described here. (This is not for my personal mail, its to read data and post it to a website. I would rather not use email to acheive this, but I do not have a choice here.)

Any idea how to do this? Code Examples? Anything is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [IMAP Extension](https://www.php.net/imap) should provide you with what you need, assuming you have it or have the ability to install it.